# Al recorrer scroll de listview me borrar datos de edittext

Tags: java, android, edittext, listview, scroll

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas tardes tengo un listview que lleno con un adaptador personalizado
en el cual tengo un edittext para que el usuario pueda poner una cantidad, el probllema es cuando tengo en mis listview mas de 5 renglones e ingreso en el primero una cantida y recorro mis scroll hacia abajo y despues me regreso hacia arriba se pierde la informacion que tenia en ese edittext

les dejo mi codigo

```
public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DetalleCxP> ArrayClientes) {
            super(context, 0, ArrayClientes);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            DetalleCxP O_DetalleCxP = getItem(position);
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_detalle, parent, false);
                ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).addTextChangedListener(new TB_Abono_Watcher(convertView));
            }

            DecimalFormat numberFormat  = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFecha)).setText(dateFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getFecha()));

            //O_DetalleCxP.setViewChanged(true);
            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setTag(O_DetalleCxP);
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio)).setText(O_DetalleCxP.getFolio());


            if (O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado>0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ((EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");
            }
           // ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado));

            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.total)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getTotal()));
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttotal)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getSaldo()));
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvencido)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getSaldoVencido()));
            //((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.parcialidad)).setText((numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getParcialidadTotal()) +" - "+ O_DetalleCxP.getParcialidad()));
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagoforma)).setText(O_DetalleCxP.getPagoCondicionDescripcion());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.UltimoCobroObservacion)).setText(O_DetalleCxP.getUltimoCobroObservacion());


            //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

y en este codigo yo hago una suma de las cantidades ingresadas en el edittext

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {

            //Abono = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono);
            DetalleCxP O_DetalleCxP = (DetalleCxP)((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).getTag();


                O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado=ONC_SYS.NullToZeroDouble(s.toString());

                Double Total=0.0;
                for(int i=0;i<DetalleArrayList.size();i++)
                {
                    if (((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado>0)
                    {
                        Total += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado;
                    }
                }
                DecimalFormat numberFormat  = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Total)).setText(numberFormat.format(Total));

                if (Total==0)
                {
                    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pagoceros)).setEnabled(true);
                    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pagoceros)).setEnabled(false);
                    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(true);
                }

                //Validacion que no te deje hacer un abono Mayo al saldo vencido
                if (O_DetalleCxP.getSaldo() < O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No puedes Aplicar un Abono Mayor al SaldoVencido",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");

                }
```

Comment: Claro, esta la pregunta que comentas? te refieres a que el valor se pierde en el editText?

Comment: si esa misma...

Comment: Ok ya veo, El elemento que quieres conservar el valor es el Edittext únicamente?

Comment: si es que lo que el usuario pone en el edittext yo lo sumo y esa suma la muestro en textview y ese dato del edittext no quiere que se borre cuando  hagan scroll

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tienes que agregar el texto vacio cuando creas la vista, cuando el convertView es Null:

```
 if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_detalle, parent, false);
            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).addTextChangedListener(new TB_Abono_Watcher(convertView));
            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setTag(O_DetalleCxP);
             ((EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");
        }
```

Comment: haber deja le intento

Comment: YA LO DEJA PERO AL HACER HACIA ABAJO EL SCROLL ME PONE LA CANTIDAD QUE INSERTE AL INICIO EN LA PARTE DE ABAJO

Comment: te voy adjunta la imagen

Comment: Hugo a que cantidad te refieres ??? "1000"

Comment: si mira yo ingreso 1000 pesos en el primer renglon, entonces si hago hacia abajo el scroll me pone esa misma cantida de 1000 en otro edittext me lo duplica

Comment: si me supe explicar ???

Comment: Hola Hugo ya veo e el 1000 se repite en otro editText

Comment: Elenasys estas? mecesito de tu ayuda...!!!

Comment: Hola me acabo de conectar, en que te puedo ayudar?

Comment: Acabo de hacer una publicacion sobre como guardar mis datos que obtengo de mi webservices en una bd sqlite para despues tomar esos datos y mostrarlos en mi listview, me ayudarias

Comment: @HugoRodriguez si esta respuesta te ayudó a solucionar el problema, deberías aceptarla haciendo click en el **✅** a la izquierda de la misma.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no notificas los cambios que insertas, y cuando haces scroll, se descarga de la memoria y cuando vuelves a la misma posición, te muestra el valor que hay inicialmente.

Para solucionarlo, debes especificar los cambios cuando entras los datos

```
tuadaptador.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: @Webservices este codigo en que parte va?

Comment: después de que el usuario meta los valores en el edittext de cada elemento, debes efectuar el cambio en tu arrayadapter, cuando tenga tiempo y aun no este resuelta mirare de crear un ejemplo y lo posteo.
aquí mas o menos lo implementan 
https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/